# What's the difference between @$filter and $filter?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, x-editable

I'm new in angularjs. I'm using [angular-xeditable](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/93/). I've selectable fields in my view. There is problem with default value of select field(last selected).

This works without errors, but not properly

```
class MyCtrl
  constructor: ($scope, @$filter, @$log) ->
    actions=[]


  showActions: (action) ->
    selected = []
    if action then selected = $filter('filter')(@actions, {name: action})
    if selected.length then return selected[0].name else return "Not set"

controllersModule.controller 'MyCtrl', MyCtrl
```

if I use `$filter` without `@` it gives error:

```
class MyCtrl
  constructor: ($scope, $filter, @$log) ->
    actions=[]


  showActions: (action) ->
    selected = []
    if action then selected = $filter('filter')(@actions, {name: action})
    if selected.length then return selected[0].name else return "Not set"

controllersModule.controller 'MyCtrl', MyCtrl
```

**Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: 
                            {{ mc.showActions(flow.action)}}**

ReferenceError: $filter is not defined

My questions are:

1. Whats difference @$ and $ in angularjs
2. Why does not work as expected in my case?

**piece of code from my html**

```
   <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as mc">
    ...
    <td>
        <span editable-select="flow.action" e-name="action" onshow="mc.getActions()"
              e-ng-options="action.id as action.name for action in mc.actions"
              e-form="rowform" e-required>
            {{ mc.showActions(flow.action)}}
        </span>
    </td>
    ...
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right now, the tabs alone in your code example would cause problems. `showActions` would be on a separate object and not at all part of MyCtrl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here problem related to `editable-select` and `e-ng-options`. The problem is that, their values are not equal to each one. I mean

```
editable-select="flow.action"
e-ng-options="action.id as action.name for action in mc.actions"

flow.action = "string"
action.id = 5

5 not equal to "string"
```

In fact, It works without `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

the reason you couldn't use just `$filter` is because you did not have the context of that argument from the `showActions` instance method. in the constructor using `@$filter` is the same as assigning it to `this.$filter` in the body of the constructor; creating a local copy of that function/object to be used within the context of the instance object. Without assigning it to a local copy that can be accessed by the instance of `MyCtl` it is no longer available outside the constructor.